# what is the difference between a == b and (a & b) == b

Tags: c#, boolean-operations

I read some script and seem to be complicated to understand. Hope someone can explain why 
The first:

```
public static bool ContainsDestroyWholeRowColumn(BonusType bt)
    {
        return (bt & BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn) 
            == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn;
    }
```

Why don't write `bt.Equal(BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn)` or `bt == BonusType.DestroyWhoeRowColumn` ?
The Second:

```
public bool IsSameType(Shape otherShape)
    {
        if (otherShape == null || !(otherShape is Shape))// check otherShape is not null and it is Shape
            throw new ArgumentException("otherShape");

        return string.Compare(this.Type, (otherShape as Shape).Type) == 0;
    }
```

if input method is not the right Type. I think It will be alert immediately, why they also need to check the type of object
The last:

```
//if we are in the middle of the calculations/loops
            //and we have less than 3 matches, return a random one
            if(row >= Constants.Rows / 2 && matches.Count > 0 && matches.Count <=2)
                return matches[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, matches.Count - 1)];
```

I thought these code always return 0;
What happened? The writer was wrong or I missed some basic knowledge. 
Please help me if you know. Thanks

Comment: `3 & 1 == 1`, but `3 != 1`.

Comment: @Mat: Those are not integer types here, though (I think, the question does not say).

Comment: Yes. a and b are not integer, In this case, it is BonusType

Answer (score 8):

This means `BonusType` is a flag type enum where multiple values can be combined using bitwise operations.

`(bt & BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn) == BonusType.DestroyWholeRowColumn` means we are checking whether `DestroyWholeRowColumn` flag is set on bt variable.

We can also check the enum flag using [Enum.HasFlag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) method but it is only available .Net 4 onwards.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c) for more information on flag type enums.

Comment: Thanks so must. I see at all. So, you can help me to explain the others question. I answer 3 question. Thanks in advance.
Maybe we should use string.compare instead of string.Equal(string) ?

Comment: You can read the question/answer on enums I provided, to get the answer to your second question. I didn't get your third question though.

Answer (score 1):

**1st Question**

`a == b` is testing that both `a` and `b` are the same value.
`(a & b) == b`, `a` is bitmask (contains multiple bit value) and is checking if the bit `b` is on.